# Image not loading from controller

Tags: angularjs, html

Hi i am trying to build a website using angularjs. The image is not showing, but the image link location is displaying. The code for the controller is given below:

```
 app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.apps = [
    {
        icon: '/img/skype.jpg',
        title: 'Skype - free IM & video calls',
        developer: 'Skype',
        price: 3
    }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
    <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card" ng-repeat="app in apps">
        <app-info info="app"></app-info>
        <install-app></install-app>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the app-info code:

```
    app.directive('appInfo', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html'
};
```

});

Here is the app-info html code:

```
<img class="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}">
<h2 class="title">{{ info.title }}</h2>
<p class="developer">{{ info.developer }}</p>
<p class="price">{{ info.price | currency }}</p>
```

Comment: where are you showing the icon? and what is install-app?

Comment: I am calling the controller, MainController and it is displaying the json object. It is a directive file named install-app.

Comment: Can you show html of templates for `<app-info>` and `<install-app>` directives?

Comment: @EganWolf 
app-info 
`code`
        
        `img class="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}">
<h2 class="title">{{ info.title }}</h2>
<p class="developer">{{ info.developer }}</p>
<p class="price">{{ info.price | currency }}</p>`

install-app
`code`

        `<button class="btn btn-active" ng-click="download()">
    {{ buttonText }}
</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide code in your appInfo directive.

And you can add in your appInfo directive template code like

```
<img src="{{info.icon}}"> or <img ng-src="{{info.icon}}">
```

Also, check if your icon is passing to your directive and

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html',
    link: function(scope, element) {
       console.log(scope.info.icon);
    }
};
```

Comment: You have to use `ng-src` in this case.

Comment: According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc): "[In case of src] The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}."

Answer (score 0):

```
 app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
$scope.image =
    {
        icon: '/img/skype.jpg',
        title: 'Skype - free IM & video calls',
        developer: 'Skype',
        price: 3
    }
```

And your HTML code

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <img ng-src="{{image.icon}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to write the controller by this way